# Material UI Grid - last item of container not taking up whole space

Tags: css, flexbox, material-ui

I have a Grid container with 2 Grid columns, each of this column having 3 elements. I want the last element of each column to be at the bottom of the column. What am I missing?

Code and behaviour below: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-311tf?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this set`margin-top` to `auto` to both the last grid item. It'll take the available margin in the top will move to the bottom of the grid container. 

I've just added `style={{marginTop:'auto'}}` to both grid items.
Here is the working code:- https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-740g8